# how to save data from dynamically added text fields in database using php

Tags: javascript, php

i have a form with texfeilds added dynamically by javascript.am using an array to extract the textfeild values in a php file. all seems to be well. but am havin trouble saving the data into the database. please help. below is my code.

form values here

```
    <form method="POST" id="theForm" action="invpdf.php"><div id="fields">
    <input type="text" name="fields[barcode][]"/>
    <input type="text" name="fields[description][]"/>
    <input type="text" id="unity"name="fields[unitprice][]" />
    <input type="text" id="qty"name="fields[qty][]"/>
     <input type="text" id="total"name="fields[total][]"/>

    <br/>
</div>
 <input type="button" id="addField" value="Add Field"/></form>
```

javascript to add textfeilds

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#addField').click(function() {
        $('#fields').append(
            $('<input type="text" name="fields[barcode][]"/>'),
            $('<input type="text" name="fields[description][]"/>'),
              $('<input type="text" name="fields[unitprice][]"/>'),
            $('<input type="text" name="fields[qty][]"/>'),
              $('<input type="text" name="fields[total][]"/>'),

            $('<br/>')
        );
    })
    });
</script>
```

my php processing as this code below

```
     $numemma = count($_POST['fields']['barcode']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numemma; $i++) {
$field = array(
    'barcode' => $_POST['fields']['barcode'][$i],
    'description' => $_POST['fields']['description'][$i],
    'unitprice' => $_POST['fields']['unitprice'][$i],
     'qty' => $_POST['fields']['qty'][$i],
    'total' => $_POST['fields']['total'][$i]
);

$feeilds = '`'.implode('`,`', $field).'`';
$data = '\''.implode('\',\'',$field).'\'';
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `sales`($feeilds)VALUES($data)");
    }
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the input at all.

Comment: What does "having trouble saving" mean more specifically? Any error messages? Have you checked your error log? You should echo your insert query, I don't think it will look like you expect it to.